# "to give in" (phr v) a homework meaning?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

"to give in" in this sentence: "Have you given in your homework yet?" What means? 
I have no ideas how to translate it into Russian. 
thanks

Comment: In the US we say "hand in" or "turn in" for submitting homework to the teacher.

Answer (score 2):

I would presume it means to submit your homework to your teacher.

But as StoneyB says, we normally say "turn in" or "hand in".

In general, to "give in" means to surrender, to let someone else have their way. Like, "Al wanted to go the car show but his girlfriend Mary wanted to go to the ballet. Finally Al gave in and they went to the ballet."

Answer (score 2):

In your example

> to **give in** your homework

the equivalent phrases would be

> **hand in** your homework
>   **turn in** your homework
>   **submit** your homework
>   **pass in** your homework
>   **check in** your homework *(digital)*
>   **deposit** your homework *(digital)*
>   **send in** your homework *(digital, possibly remote)*